# Why sudden spike in egress cost in GCP App engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I have deployed 3 app engine services in the flex environment. Each service has 2-3 versions. For the past few days, I am facing high egress costs. I am not able to pinpoint what is the reason for the high egress cost. The cost occurs in the cloud storage section. But there are no buckets used in my project. Only app engine services. Few details that I gathered are:

1) Project is in the Australia region, but the app engine service is used by people in Asia region. 
2) Some buckets with the prefix "asia.artifact" is created automatically in cloud storage.

I am not getting the actual reason for such a spike in egress cost.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Platform providing all GCP users free billing support.

If you have any concerns about your cost,

you can contact GCP billing support team directly about your case with no cost.

It provides both [Live Chat support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/chat) and [Phone support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/phone).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#flexible-environment-pricing) you can find all the information regarding the App Engine Flexible Environment Pricing details. App Engine resources are billed on a per-second basis with a 1 minute minimum usage cost.

The corresponding Pricing details for Cloud Storage you may find [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).

Additionally, Google Cloud Platform offers the [Cloud Billing Reports page](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports), which lets you view your Google Cloud usage costs at a glance and discover and analyze trends.

Moreover, in order to avoid surprises on your bill you can [manage your App Engine costs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managing-costs) by [creating budgets](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets) to monitor all your Google Cloud charges in one place. After you've set a budget amount, you set budget alert rules that are used to trigger notifications, so you can stay informed about how your spend is tracking against your budget.

[Here](https://www.mattzeunert.com/2019/11/25/understanding-my-october-google-cloud-bill.html), I found some interesting non-official documentation breaking down a personal GCP Billing Report that could be helpful, as well as a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58845675/google-cloud-storage-egress-high-cost-how-can-i-reduce-it) on reducing egress cost on Cloud Storage.
In addition to that, you may find Google's latest news on optimizing costs while using GCP products [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/best-practices-for-optimizing-your-cloud-costs) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/storage-data-transfer/best-practices-for-cloud-storage-cost-optimization).

If the spikes you see still seem unreasonable, then the best solution as suggested by @Brent Chang would be to contact [GCP Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing).